# Laravel Storage Ftp returns Could not login with connection

Tags: laravel

I am using [`Storage::createFtpDriver`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/FilesystemManager.php#L172). But I want to validate the credentials before proceeding.

If I do `$ftp->exists(self::REMOTE_FILE_DEST)` then I am getting the error, I would like boolean instead, so I can work with it.

Error I am getting looks:

> Could not login with connection: xxxxxxx

Code I currently have is:

```
$ftp = Storage::createFtpDriver([
    'host'     => getSetting(SettingRepository::FTP_HOST)->getvalue(),
    'username' => getSetting(SettingRepository::FTP_USERNAME)->getvalue(),
    'password' => getSetting(SettingRepository::FTP_PASSWORD)->getvalue(),
    'port'     => getSetting(SettingRepository::FTP_PORT)->getvalue(),
    'timeout'  => getSetting(SettingRepository::FTP_TIMEOUT)->getvalue(),
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catch exception and return `true`/`false` on that.

```
try {
    Storage::createFtpDriver([...]);
    return true;
} catch (Exception $e) { // If I looked correctly it is RuntimeException so you can be more explicit
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Very strange, i did tried that. It works now... Thanks!